# Angular2 Html inside a Component

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want create a component like a template. For example, instead of writing this everywhere:

```
<div class="myClass">
    <div class="myHeader" id="headerId"> Title </div>
    <div class="myContent" id="contentId"> <<Some HTML code>> </div>
</div>
```

I want to use a component like:

```
<my-component title="Title" headerID=headerId contentID=contentID>
    <<Some HTML code>>
</my-component>
```

How can I implement something like these in Angular2?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem? How is `<<Some HTML code>>` related to the question?

Comment: I didn't tried anything since I am not very experienced in Angular2. I googled it but could not find anything similar to what I want. I am looking for suggestions here.

Comment: So what do you want? What is the desired behavior or result? If you just create a simple component, what does it not do what you want?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use `<ng-content></ng-content>` in your component.

`my.component.html`

```
<div class="myClass">
    <div class="myHeader" id="headerId"> Title </div>
    <div class="myContent" id="contentId"> <ng-content></ng-content> </div>
</div>
```

`parent.component.html`

```
<my-component title="Title" headerID=headerId contentID=contentID>
    <<Some HTML code>>
</my-component>
```

Whatever is inside `<my-component></mycomponent>` will be rendered in `<ng-content></ng-content>`

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to force lazy loading of content? If I conditinally include <ng-content> in my component, all content gets initialized even if condition is false - eg when contents contains some other components.