# How to show a HTML Dom/ Angular Component inside a Angular component?

Tags: angular

I have a simple `component` named `rectangle` with a simple `css`. Now I need to show a element example a `div` or another `component` inside that component. How would I achieve this?

---

I tried doing:

```html
<app-rectangle>
  <div>
   ...
 </div>
</app-rectangle>
```

and nothing showed up as the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called Content Projection.

In the template of the `<app-rectangle>` component add the following:

`<ng-content></ng-content>`

Your div should automatically appear within those tags.

See more here: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#responding-to-projected-content-changes

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `<ng-content></ng-content>`
I believe you are looking for something similar that was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39292195/angular2-html-inside-a-component).

Answer (score 1):

Add `<ng-content></ng-content>` to the component's template where the content should be projected, Here I created a sample on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-96bdgy?file=src/app/app.component.html) for you

**hello.component.html**

```html
<h1>Hello from Component</h1>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<hello>
  <h1>Hello between component</h1>
</hello>
```